# Not able to find aray index out of bound exception cause

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

```
for(int i = q.length-1; i >= 0; i--){
        if(q[i] != i+1){
            try{
                if(((i-1)>=0) & (q[i-1] == (i+1))){

                    steps++;
                    q[i-1] = q[i];

                    q[i] = i+1;
                    System.out.println("here "+i);
                }
                if(((i-2) >=0) & (q[i-2] == (i+1))){

                    q[i-2] = q[i-1];
                    q[i-1] = q[i];
                    q[i] = i+1;
                    steps += 2;
                }else{
                    System.out.println("Too chaotic");
                    return;
                }
            }catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println("error at the " +i + " exception" +e);
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(steps);
```

*
The last value of i, I get in the catch is 1. I tried to print i in the if condition and it is printing the i value as 1 till the last line. Now, I don't understand where the exception is happening?
*

Comment: Is the stack trace not telling you the line with the exception?

Comment: you can put the objects that q has it?

Comment: You are using bitwise `&`. Did you want logical `&&`?

Comment: Yes that's probably your mistake. If the if statement evaluates to true that means you will try to access `q[-1]` on the next line.

Comment: Thank you so much guys for your responses. I am new in programming and I made a stupid mistake. @JohnnyMopp your suggestion was right, As soon as I changed it to && the error was gone. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Inside the second nested-if statement, you try to access `q[i-2]`. But you try to do so only after checking if `i - 2 >= 0`, right? Wrong! You have used the bitwise AND (`&`) instead of a logical AND (`&&`).

`if(((i-2) >=0) & (q[i-2] == (i+1)))`

If it were a logical AND, the next condition inside the statement will not be checked if `i - 2` was less than 0, thus preventing the access to `q[i - 2]`. Since it is a bitwise AND, both the operands will be evaluated and the **evaluation of `q[i - 2]` at i = 1** causes the Array Index Out Of Bound exception.

That is why, the last value of `i` you get in the catch is 1.

This is a sufficient reason to throw the exception, but the same problem stays with the first nested-if statement. It could have been caused by this if you were traversing the array in the other direction or if there was no problem at `i = 1`. Therefore, in order to prevent this error, you should change both of those `&` into `&&`.